# Beaglebone can't start OS after unplugging supply power

Tags: beagleboneblack

I'm using beaglebone black (Debian OS, MySQL are installed).
After **unplugging supply** power and not **using 24 hours**.
I can't start my beaglebone. 
It's only birght LED D4 and power LED.
How can i start my OS?

I just try to use usb cable and access to beaglebone at 192.168.7.2. but request time out.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that the operating system has become corrupted by the unexpected shutdown. The same thing can happen with a regular computer and has happened with my own beaglebone black when I pulled the power plug while testing some circuits. I would suggest trying to boot off of an SD card. If you have anything on there you want to save, you can use the live SD card OS to retrieve the data from the embedded flash. If the SD card also doesnt boot, then you may have a hardware issue and a serial to USB cable plugged into the debug header would probably be needed to try and get more information as to why it is not booting.

Comment: I used cable...... It's not working.

I reinstall my OS. :(
Thank you for answering my question.